# So "tags" for versions and "branches" for new features?

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial, github, bitbucket

I'm a little bit new to the distributed version control systems, so I was reading Mercurial manual and what I understood is the tag feature can be used to mark release numbers, example a tag called v1.0 and another v1.1, etc.

As for branches they are to be used to add new features without disturbing other developers then merge it with the *default* branch after everything is OK.

Is that right?

Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a good way to use the functionality.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like you're mostly getting answers from git folks, who almost understand Mercurial too.

The core difference is that in git the branch name isn't an integral part of a changeset -- it's just where the changeset happens to be now.  In mercurial a Named Branch's name is part of it forever.  This leads folks who know git more than they know Mercurial to say one of two **not-quite correct** things:

- *Named branches should be used on a per-feature basis* -- There's nothing wrong with using a named branch per feature in Mercurial, but since those branch names never go away your `hg branches` output can grow quite large.
- *Branching in Mercurial isn't as lightweight as in git* -- **Named Branching** in Mercurial isn't quite as lightweight (they're permanent) but that's why it's not the norm for features.  Anonymous branching in Mercurial is more lightweight than git's named branches, and Bookmark branching in Mercurial is exactly the same as git branching.

All of this is spelled out beautifully in Steve Losh's [Guide to Branching in Mercurial](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2009/08/a-guide-to-branching-in-mercurial/), as originally answered by OJ (which I upvoted).

In summary:

- git

  - releases: tags
  - features: branches
  - lines of development (stable, etc.): separate repositories
- mercurial:

  - releases: tags
  - features: bookmarks or anonymous branches
  - lines of development (stable, etc.): named branches

Of course, either tool can be used in either fashion -- it's more about norms than it is about "correct".

Comment: Why do you suggest splitting lines of development in git into separate repositories? I don't really get it.

Comment: From what I've heard, bookmark branching is not quite as flexible as git's branches in terms of transferring between repositories, and the anonymity of anonymous branches can be problematic.

Comment: Bookmarks can be pushed nowadays with some option, and anonymous branches are not problematic if you just clone your repository into a new directory with a nice descriptive name.

Comment: @Laurens: But what if you don't want a clone for every single branch? That's definitely not lightweight. And on another question here, I was told that bookmarks are not as configurable as git's branches for pushing - more of an all-or-nothing thing. I stand by what I said.

Comment: Jefromi, there has never been anything all-or-nothing about `push` in mercurial, be-it by renumber, branchname, tagname, or bookmark name.  What surprised git-folks at first is that the default is 'all' but you can always use -r to push only what you want.  Sjl put together a 'nudge' alias for git people that prefer the git behavior -- it's one line.

Comment: Mercurial versions >1.2 allow you to close branches after your are done with them.  After you do that you can get a list of just active branches with "hg branches --active", more on that here: http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PruningDeadBranches

Comment: and in 1.6 and later you can not just make named branches inactive, but also `hg commit --close-branch` them, but they still show up in `hg heads` and other places.  Named branches in Mercurial are great, but they're anything but light weight -- that's what anonymous branches and bookmarks are for.

Answer (score 5):

Have a read of the following to help clarify your understanding (Mercurial related):

- [A guide to branching in Mercurial](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2009/08/a-guide-to-branching-in-mercurial/)
- [Mercurial Workflows: Branch as Needed](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2010/02/mercurial-workflows-branch-as-needed/)
- [Mercurial Workflows: Stable and Default](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2010/05/mercurial-workflows-stable-default/)
- [Mercurial Workflows: Translation Branches](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2010/06/mercurial-workflows-translation-branches/)

Answer (score 3):

Well that's a question that depends on your point of view. In **git**, branches are used for a lot of purposes ( i.e. one is development). In fact, everything in git is **branch**. And there may be different **tags** in each branch.

I've would recommended to read this gread tutorial, as it explains a lot of things about branches and releases:

http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Answer (score 2):

The two answers about git correctly agree with you that tags are good for releases, and branches are good for new features, but don't really explain why.

A git tag permanently points to a given commit. This means that it's really *only* good for marking a milestone like a release.

A branch, on the other hand, can be checked out and committed to, meaning the branch will advance to point to that new commit. This makes branches *the* way to work in git; any time you make a commit you want to have an appropriate branch checked out, so that it will record your progress. This includes new features, as you say, but also any other work.

The situation in Mercurial is mostly similar, though branching is not quite so lightweight, so you won't be branching as frequently as you would in git. And tags are handled a bit differently, but are still good for marking releases.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Mercurial user (I use Git), but as far as the Git work flow goes you've got it dead on. Branches are used, often by one developer, to work on their own bugfixes/features before merging with the main branch.

Tags are normally used on the main branch to tag milestones, often releases. This lets you revert to that state easily, without having to use commit numbers (which in Git are long strings of hexadecimal digits, not sure how Mercurial works).

Gary